# Google script - function not looping based on if statement

Tags: logging, google-sheets

This is a massive script (for me at least) and it's sooo sooo sooo close to being completed!

Just a few more teething issues remain, so I'm hoping for some help to get it completed and working as it's nearing beyond my comprehension!

The current issues are:

1. Code does not loop after first run - not sure why? I don't think i=1 is < SessionNamesArraySize: 26 (minus 1, 25)
2. "T" is NOT the first item in the array? Not sure why it's only pulling a singular character - you can see this at the end of the console log

Purpose of code: creates column for each item in the array - fills it with G sheets formulas which pull data from 2 tabs of combined data - I will be adding to this a few extra final functions once this part is done.

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aZBNp6b47-qp-1m-1dX0XtnGG2o1Nrs4AbckGInt0t8/edit#gid=878821914

Console below the code...

Here is the code:

```
//Build session reports
function allSessionNames2() {

//All Available variables
var TemplateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
Logger.log("TemplateSheet: " + TemplateSheet);
var TemplateTab = TemplateSheet[3].getName();
Logger.log("TemplateTab: " + TemplateTab);
var OverviewSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var overviewTab = OverviewSheet[0].getName();
var CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2];
var CurrentSpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var CurrentTab
var OnAIRSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var OnAIRTab = OnAIRSheet[2]
var CurrentSessionName = "";
var DetailsColumn;
FindDetailsColumn();
//Find the Details Column in OnAIR Tab
function FindDetailsColumn() {
for (var i = 1; i < OnAIRTab.getLastColumn() ; i++) {
  if (OnAIRTab.getRange(1,i).getValue() == "Details") {
    Logger.log("I: " + i);
    DetailsColumn = i;
    break;
  }
}
}

var DetailsColumnLetter = ColumnToLetter(DetailsColumn);
//Convert DetailsColumn into letter
function ColumnToLetter(DetailsColumnLetter)
{
  var Temp, Letter = '';
  while (DetailsColumnLetter > 0)
  {
    Temp = (DetailsColumnLetter - 1) % 26;
    Letter = String.fromCharCode(Temp + 65) + Letter;
    DetailsColumnLetter = (DetailsColumnLetter - Temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return Letter;
  Logger.log("Letter: " + Letter);
}


Logger.log("DetailsColumn: " + DetailsColumn);
var DetailsColumnRange = DetailsColumnLetter + '2:' + DetailsColumnLetter;
Logger.log("DetailsColumnRange: " + DetailsColumnRange);
var DetailsColumnFilter = '=COUNTIF(' + DetailsColumnRange + ',' + DetailsColumnRange + ')=1';
DetailsColumnFilter.toString();
Logger.log("DetailsColumnFilter: " + DetailsColumnFilter);

//Filter Unique values in the details Column
function FilterUniqueDetailsColumn() {
  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Spreadsheet.getRange(DetailsColumnRange).activate();
  var Criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied(DetailsColumnFilter)
  .build();
  if (OnAIRTab.getFilter() != null) {
    OnAIRTab.getFilter().remove();
  }
  //OnAIRTab.getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(9,Criteria);
  OnAIRTab.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(9,Criteria);
};

FilterUniqueDetailsColumn();

var LastRow = OnAIRTab.getLastRow();
var SessionNamesArray = OnAIRTab.getRange(2, DetailsColumn, LastRow, 1).getValues();
var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW OnAIR');
var Filter1 = Sheet1.getRange(DetailsColumnRange).getFilter();
var SessionNamesArrayUnique = [];
SessionNamesArray.forEach(function(x){
  if(SessionNamesArrayUnique.indexOf(x[0]) === -1){
    SessionNamesArrayUnique.push(x[0]);
  }
});
//Filter1.getColumnFilterCriteria(DetailsColumn).getVisibleValues();
Logger.log("SessionNamesArrayUnique: " + SessionNamesArrayUnique);
var SessionNamesArraySize = SessionNamesArrayUnique.length;
var TemplateContentsA = "Session Name";
var TemplateContentsB = "Contact Identifier";
var Range1 = "B1";
var Range2 = "A1";
var Range3 = "A3";
var Range4 = "A4";
var Formula1 = "=iferror(FILTER(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!B:V,REGEXMATCH(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!O:O,B1)),\"\Session does not exist\"\)";
var Formula2 = '=FILTER(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!1:1,\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!B1 = \"\Contact Identifier\"\)';



//1. Fill Formula on Overview page
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A4").setFormula("=UNIQUE('RAW OnAIR'!P2:P)");
Logger.log("Fill Formula on Overview tab - cell A4")

//2. Retrieve all sessions into array
Logger.log("SessionNamesUniqueArray: " + SessionNamesArrayUnique);
Logger.log("SessionNamesArraySize: " + SessionNamesArraySize);

//3. Begin loop for creating a tab per session
for (var i = 1; i < SessionNamesArraySize - 1; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
  Logger.log("Starting Tab creation loop");
  Logger.log("Variable i: " + i);
} else {
  Logger.log("restarting tab creation loop");
  Logger.log("Variable i: " + i);
}
  if (SessionNamesArrayUnique[i][0] === "") {
    continue;
  } else {
    Logger.log("SessionNamesArrayUnique:" + SessionNamesArrayUnique[i][0]);
  var ActiveSessionName = SessionNamesArrayUnique[i][0];
  Logger.log("Current Session name: " + SessionNamesArrayUnique[i][0]);
  Logger.log("Current Session name: " + ActiveSessionName);
  //Create new sheet + paste code
  CurrentSpread.insertSheet(ActiveSessionName);
  //Paste code
  Logger.log("Setting active range B1 - set value...");
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range1).setValue(ActiveSessionName);
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range2).setValue("Session Name:");
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range4).setFormula(Formula1);
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range3).setFormula(Formula2);
  Logger.log("Setting values in cells.... Done.")
  
}

//4. Confirm tab count equals total session count minus the first 3 tabs
    return Logger.log("Loop completed for sessions: " + ActiveSessionName);
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
4:42:48 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:42:48 PM  Info    TemplateSheet: Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet
4:42:48 PM  Info    TemplateTab: Template
4:42:49 PM  Info    I: 9
4:42:49 PM  Info    DetailsColumn: 9
4:42:49 PM  Info    DetailsColumnRange: I2:I
4:42:49 PM  Info    DetailsColumnFilter: =COUNTIF(I2:I,I2:I)=1
4:42:53 PM  Info    SessionNamesArrayUnique: ,Tech Check Session for Moderators,AWM | Together to Win,Plenary,RECON | Real Intelligence,AWM | 2021 Channel Strategy,AWM | Hospital & Community Strategy  Execution,AWM | Pharmacy Strategy Execution,2. Global Supply Chain | Yasheen Nunkumar,1. Corporate Accounts & Government Affairs | Maroun El Khoury,3. Human Resources | Diana Da Silva,6. Regulatory & Quality | Minta Chen,Survey Test,4. Legal | Alan Boys,5. Medical Education | Mark Penno,6. Regulatory & Quality | Minta Chen v2,AWM | Pharmacy Team,AWM | Hospital Team,AWM | Community Team,SPM Day 2,RECON | Knees and Hips,AKOM 2021 Awards,AWM Day 3,SPM Day 3,RECON | Trauma,7. IT | Rohit Gupta
4:42:53 PM  Info    Fill Formula on Overview tab - cell A4
4:42:53 PM  Info    SessionNamesUniqueArray: ,Tech Check Session for Moderators,AWM | Together to Win,Plenary,RECON | Real Intelligence,AWM | 2021 Channel Strategy,AWM | Hospital & Community Strategy  Execution,AWM | Pharmacy Strategy Execution,2. Global Supply Chain | Yasheen Nunkumar,1. Corporate Accounts & Government Affairs | Maroun El Khoury,3. Human Resources | Diana Da Silva,6. Regulatory & Quality | Minta Chen,Survey Test,4. Legal | Alan Boys,5. Medical Education | Mark Penno,6. Regulatory & Quality | Minta Chen v2,AWM | Pharmacy Team,AWM | Hospital Team,AWM | Community Team,SPM Day 2,RECON | Knees and Hips,AKOM 2021 Awards,AWM Day 3,SPM Day 3,RECON | Trauma,7. IT | Rohit Gupta
4:42:53 PM  Info    SessionNamesArraySize: 26
4:42:53 PM  Info    Starting Tab creation loop
4:42:53 PM  Info    Variable i: 1
4:42:53 PM  Info    SessionNamesArrayUnique:T
4:42:53 PM  Info    Current Session name: T
4:42:53 PM  Info    Current Session name: T
4:42:53 PM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
4:42:53 PM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
4:42:53 PM  Info    Loop completed for sessions: T
4:42:55 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Any help would be great - if you see areas of improvement with the code I'll take it all onboard this was done with a bare minimum G script experience and I've been learning and implementing this for about a month or 2. This is all in the name of time saving hahah.

Thanks,
Mitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1, the return inside the loop ends the loop:

```
return Logger.log("Loop completed for sessions: " + ActiveSessionName);
```

---

Issue 2:

> "T" is NOT the first item in the array? Not sure why it's only pulling
> a singular character - you can see this at the end of the console log

Change:

```
var ActiveSessionName = SessionNamesArrayUnique[i][0];
```

To:

```
var ActiveSessionName = SessionNamesArrayUnique[i];
```

---

You could simplify the code in many places.

For example, call the sheet once and get all the tabs at that time:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var TemplateTab = ss.getSheetByName('DATA OVERVIEW');
var OnAIRSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RAW OnAIR');
```

... etc

The `FindDetailsColumn` function can be simplified to one line:

```
var DetailsColumnLetter = String.fromCharCode(i + 64);
```

---

**Edit**: For columns beyond Z, you could try:

```
var DetailsColumnRange = OnAIRTab.getRange(2, i).getA1Notation();
var colName = DetailsColumnRange.match(/\D+/)[0];
DetailsColumnRange = DetailsColumnRange + ":" + colName;
```

---

Best not to call the sheet for data from each cell:

```
OnAIRTab.getRange(1, i).getValue()
```

Better to get the entire data range ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)) and iterate through it.

DM me if you need help. All the best.

Comment: Of course my return was within the loop! I've been staring at my code for too long!

Issue 2: A interesting is it because it goes from 2d to 1d? hence why I don't need the [0]?

Plenty of simplification to be done! I'll review everything now it's working! 

Does the FindDetailsColumn work if it is double characters? in your suggestion above?

Calling cell by cell does this cost more than loading the whole sheet and then iterating through it? For speed purposes or for easy of coding?

Thanks again for assisting! Finally got this working!

Comment: I've added an edit with an idea on how to solve for columns beyond Z. Calling cell by cell uses a lot of system resources. It works faster to get all the data in one go and then iterate.